# Maven - How to obtain all the dependent artifacts

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have a project that needs to be deployed, and I want to get its jar alongside with all the dependent jars.

What's the easiest way of doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the maven dependency plugin:

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.8</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/alternateLocation</outputDirectory>
              <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
              <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
              <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

Above copied from the mojo documentation describing how to [Copy project dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-project-dependencies.html)

Another useful link for new maven users is [the list of maven plugins](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/index.html).